# How to exclude seconds from Input Type Time?

Tags: angularjs

I am taking Time from input type 'Time'.

And printing it using AngluarJS like `{{Employee.StartTime}}`.
But my concern is that this approach prints time in `12:15:00`.

So how to exclude seconds from the format?

Comment: Is **Employee.StartTime** a string? which you are binding inside interpolation.

Comment: write a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS It's DateTime. My bad I didn't mentioned it in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try , it will exclude the seconds format.

```
{{Employee.StartTime | date:"HH:mm}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `{{Employee.StartTime}}` is a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, then you can display it however you want using the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

If I understand correctly, you only want hours and minutes, which can be achieved as such:

`{{Employee.StartTime | date:"HH:mm}}`

Comment: Is this working on already formatted date? I guess this works only on ms date format.

Comment: It works on [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects. Not sure what format he has.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of formats to choose from as per [the angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date). You can specify it in a variable and use it something like:

**In Html:**

```
<span>{{Employee.StartTime |  date : format}}</span>
```

**In Controller:**

```
$scope.format = 'hh:mm';
```

For your case here, you can simply go for:

```
 <span>{{Employee.StartTime |  date : 'hh:mm'}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the StartTime you are getting from the Employee Object might be a string since it is returning "12:15:00" as a value without applying any filter or without any date conversion. So I have described my answer to handle that scenario below. Also please check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iIGOZ9fmWZ44hMS9Amj0?p=preview) working example of your given scenario.

**Template:**

```
{{Employee.StartTime | timeFilter}}
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Employee={
    StartTime: '12:15:00'
  };
});

app.filter('timeFilter', function($filter) {
  return function(input){
    var date=new Date();
    date.setHours(input.split(':')[0]);
    date.setMinutes(input.split(':')[1]);
    return $filter('date')(date, 'hh:mm', 'US');
  }
});
```

***Note:*** You can change format 'hh:mm' to 'HH:mm' in filter incase you need a 24 Hours format.